# how to solve Error during sub directory in python

Tags: python

path = '\2B-Data\'

Welcome Vishal Sharma. We are preparing data of 2B for you.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\Users\Vishal Sharma\Desktop\New folder (5)\2B.py", line 152, in 
for a,i in enumerate(os.listdir(path)):
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: '\2B-Data\'
PS C:\Users\Vishal Sharma\Desktop\New folder (5)>

Comment: Use ```\\``` for paths.

Answer (score 1):

for paths in python you have to prefix it with 'r'
something like

`path = r'\2B-Data\'`

An ‘r’ preceding a string denotes a raw, (almost) un-escaped string.

The escape character is backslash, that is why a normal string will not work as a Windows path string.

Answer (score 0):

try this for example:

import os
os.makedirs('folder/2B-Data', exist_ok=True)

Answer (score 0):

You can also got for something like this, if you want to go for the detailed way:

```
# importing os module
import os
 
# os.makedirs() method will raise an OSError if directory to be created already exists
# suppressed by setting exist_ok as True
    
# directory
directory = "2B-Data"
 
# parent directory path
parent_dir = "/someDirectory/subDir"
 
# path
path = os.path.join(parent_dir, directory)
 
# create the directory
try:
    os.makedirs(path, exist_ok = True)
    print("Directory '%s' created successfully" %directory)
except OSError as error:
    print("Directory '%s' can not be created")
```

Comment: Actually i dont want to create new sub directory. I want to add path like 
os.cwd() +'//2B' # or any other folder available in that current directory.

Comment: try to implement the path join method posted above, should work imo